# Four Identical dice are rolled simultaneously. Integer solution

Tags: probability, dice

Four Identical dice are rolled simultaneously . Probability that product of first two outcome is more than the product of last two outcome is **m/n**(m,n are co prime ) then value of n-2m-78 is equal to ----

I was trying to figure out various cases in which product of two numbers appearing on first two dice is greater than product of last 2 dice numbers.

D1- 1  D2 -3   D3-1 D4-1    1*3>1*1  = 3>1 I am finding difficulty in figuring out various cases...please help

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: If the dice are identical and rolled simultaneously, what are *the first two*?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh, I written what I was trying to do ....

Comment: I recommend working out this probability with 2-sided dice, then 3-sided dice, then 4, etc., until you feel capable of treating the more general problem.  Share your results here, and we can help when you get stuck.

Comment: Please use LaTeX commands for formatting your mathematical formulas. Take a look at this for basic tips: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference